# Refresh/Reinitialize Home Page - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, route-provider

I have a video that plays on my home page and when I navigate to the other pages it no longer shows (which is what I want). But when I click on a link to go back to the home page, I want the video to start playing again or even show up. What I want to do is refresh the page/state of the home page when I redirect back to it. I have attempted a few ways to try and get this to happen, but no luck! Here is my code that I have (this does not include what I have tried).

What I want to happen is when I click away from the home page and then click on the link (shown in the index.html snippet) I want the page to go back to it's original state of when the video showed and played. But you no longer see the video. The assumption is that when I move away and come back to the home page, the controller doesn't reinit, since it's already created. So I want to try and refresh or reinit the home page

**Index.html**
[image]

**HomeCtrl**

[image]

**HomeSvc**

[image]

**App.js**
[image]

I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Can you provide more information about the HomeSvc, what is it supposed to do ? Same for HomeCtrl . And can you give the html implementation of your video ?

Comment: Sorry! I put the incorrect homeCtrl up. It's being done via angular. No html code for the video. But I'm using the http://okfoc.us/okvideo/ plugin. Other than that what you see in the homeSvc and homeCtrl is what I have. I updated the needs also...

Answer (score 0):

The function on the event `$routechangestart` make the issue.
Because when you leave the home page, the player is stopped and removed from the DOM. But when you come back to home page, he's obviously removed.

Are you obliged to remove the player for stopping it ? Does it keep playing when you go to an other page if you don't delete it ?

Try it by removing the part below and tell what you get without

```
 $scope.$on($routechangestart...);
```

**EDIT**

I should have advice you giving up this plugin, very poor in my opinion.
As you use Angular, you should keep working with angular plugin instead of jquery, you have so many ones ! After a quick research, I found 2 maintained projects, the first one is [angular-video-background](https://github.com/2013gang/angular-video-background) which seem to be stable enough, and richer than okvideo. The second is [ngVideo](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ngVideo) which does pretty much the same thing. Choose what you want.

With these two angular plugins, the main advantage is the play/pause control. Then you keep your watcher on `$routechangestart` within you force pause and play depending what you reach. But one sure thing, leave this jquery plugin okvideo

**EDIT 2**

Take a  look at [videogular](http://www.videogular.com/) seems to be very popular

Comment: Removing the $routechangestart keeps the video playing no matter what page I navigate to. I would like the video to not show on my other pages, but show up and start playing again when I go back to the home page.